# AWS sagemaker invoke_endpoint error: "Unknown parameter in input: \"InferenceComponentName\""

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, llama

I am trying to create an api to call a sagemaker endpoint with a llama-python-7b inference model attached to it.

When calling `invoke_endpoint` with the `InferenceComponentName` parameter, I get `Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in input: \"InferenceComponentName\", must be one of: EndpointName, Body, ContentType, Accept, CustomAttributes, TargetModel, TargetVariant, TargetContainerHostname, InferenceId, EnableExplanations"`.

This parameter comes directly from the Python SDK example given with the sagemaker inference model. My lambda code is essentially a copy of this example:

```
import json
import boto3

endpoint_name = '<endpoint>'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
    response = client.invoke_endpoint(
        EndpointName=endpoint_name, InferenceComponentName='<inference component name>',
        ContentType='application/json',
        Body=json.dumps(event).encode('utf-8'),
    )
    response = response["Body"].read().decode("utf8")
    response = json.loads(response)
    return response
```

If I do not pass this parameter in, I get:

`An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Inference Component Name header is required for endpoints to which you plan to deploy inference components. Please include Inference Component Name header or consider using SageMaker models.`

so it's missing something, but I'm not sure what or how to format it.

I have also given the role associated with the lambda function the `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess` permission to try and eliminate permissions as the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The issue turned out to be with the version of boto3 being loaded by AWS lambda.

I was using python3.11, which comes with boto3-1.26.90, however InferenceComponentName was not added until later versions. See this page for more info on which versions ship with which interpreter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html

I was able to get load the proper version by creating a deployment.zip file containing the correct python packages and my lambda script, following the steps in this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, I have the same issue and you explanation really helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the boto3 version that is installed by default. boto3==1.34.34 worked for me. To resolve this, execute the following command to install the specified version and rerun your code:

```
!pip install boto3==1.34.34
```